# Как запретить остальным потокам выполнять код?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть код, который должен выполнятся в другом потоке если подходят условия.

Но как быть если несколько пользователей одновременно постучаться в этот код?
На каждого из них будет создан отдельный поток и код будет исполнятся столько раз,сколько пользователей попало в этот код.

synchronized блоки не помогают мне в этом т.к. потоки станут в очередь и исполнять код будут друг за другом.

Как я понимаю нужно поставить флажок , но как его реализовать не пойму.

Comment: Синхронизация нужна не для выполнения одного кода, а для обеспечения целостности данных. В коде используется доступ к одним и тем же данным?

Comment: Да,есть метод для обновление статистики.
Но если в этот метод приходят сразу 50 запросов - создается 50 потоков и все они исполняют один и тот же код.
Моя цель - если  остальные потоки увидели , что происходит исполнение метода - не выполнялись.

Comment: Код может исполняться одновременно при соблюдении некоторых условий. См. обновление первого коммента

Comment: Тут ReentrantLock может помочь. Один поток может залочить его, а другие могут проверять, свободен ли он, и пропускать блок, в случае занятости лока.